# tabcmd - pdf export not filtering correctly

Tags: tableau-api

When I run the batch file below (with login,etc), the output doesn't filter based on what I have written in the script (i.e. General Manager = Joe Jones). However, if I paste that section of code ("Report-GM/GM?General%20Manager=Joe%20Jones") on the back of the url, it filters the page correctly when I load it in the browser.

`tabcmd export "Report-GM/GM?General%20Manager=Joe%20Jones" --fullpdf --pagelayout landscape --pagesize a3 -f "C:\Users\\Desktop\Reports\JoeJones.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it needed to be coded like "Report-GM/GM?General%%20Manager=Joe%%20Jones" (with TWO percent signs)